# How to pass arguments from vimscript functions to python interface?

Tags: python, function, vim, arguments, interop

For example, processing positional arguments:

```
function! Example(arg)
python <<_EOF_

# do something with a:arg

_EOF_
endfunction
```

or the ... list:

```
function! Example(...)
python <<_EOF_

# do something with a:000, a:1, a:2, etc.

_EOF_
endfunction
```

Is there anyway I can do this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can retrieve the function arguments just like any other Vimscript expression through `vim.eval()`:

```
function! Example(arg)
python << _EOF_

import vim
print "arg is " + vim.eval("a:arg")

_EOF_
endfunction
```

Comment: and in vimscript9 Ingo?